# JavaScript : switch and check radio button

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I wrote this code to switch between radio buttons and show my custom alert.

```
<script>
    function test() {
            if (radio[0].checked = true) {
                alert("hello1");
            }

            if (radio[1].checked = true) {
                alert("hello2");
            }
    }
</script>


<input type="radio" onclick="test()" value="0">
<input type="radio" onclick="test()" value="1">
```

When check any of radio buttons it must show specific alert.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to take note here:
1) You must use the 'name' attribute in the radio button. Otherwise you won't be able to check the radio button.
2) You cannot use radio[0] to point to the radio button. You can assign an ID to it and use `getElementById` method to use it in Javascript. Another easy way is to pass the object to the function. Please refer to the sample code below:

```
<script>
    function test(radioObj) {
        if(radioObj.value == "0")
            alert("Hello1");
        else if (radioObj.value == "1")
            alert("Hello2");
    }
</script>

<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="test(this)" value="0">
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="test(this)" value="1">
```

Answer (score 3):

You should name your radio buttons, and call them from javascript.

```
<script>
    function test() {
        if (document.getElementById('radio1').checked == true) {
            alert("hello1");
        }

        if (document.getElementById('radio2').checked == true) {
            alert("hello2");
        }
    }
</script>


<input type="radio" id="radio1" onclick="test()" value="0">
<input type="radio" id="radio2" onclick="test()" value="1">
```

Comment: You got a little bug in there... "if" statement needs == for equality check instead of the single '='

Answer (score 1):

`radio[0]` and `radio[1]` are defined in your html but not in your javascript. You can try using [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) or one of the many javascript selector libraries. Or use `getElementById`